# How to check if current user has a blog/site in WordPress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress, networking, wpmu

I would like to know how can I modify the following code to check if the current user has a site/blog already set up on my wordpress network??

```
<?php 
global $wp_roles;
foreach ( $wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name ) :
    if ( current_user_can( $role ) && $role == 'administrator') { 
        if ( class_exists( 'MarketpressFadminWidget' ) ) { 
            $mp_frontend_settings = get_option( 'mp_frontend_settings' );
            $mp_frontend_settings = unserialize($mp_frontend_settings);
            $adminpage = $mp_frontend_settings['page_id'];
            $permalink = get_permalink($adminpage);
            ?>
            // My Links / Html Content
            <?php 
        }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop opening/closing each line with `<?php whatever(); ?>`, you can write it non-stop and just close/open when printing Html.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`get_blogs_of_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blogs_of_user).

> #### Description
>
> Returns an array of objects containing the details of each blog the specified user has access to.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. However I do not know how to apply this to my code/situation? I have to use the above code. The most important part of the code is ` if ( class_exists( 'MarketpressFadminWidget' ) ) { $mp_frontend_settings = get_option( 'mp_frontend_settings' ); $mp_frontend_settings = unserialize($mp_frontend_settings); $adminpage = $mp_frontend_settings['page_id']; $permalink = get_permalink($adminpage); ?>` Because it is to be used to work the marketpress plugin Im using